# How can i split a long line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, erb

I am doing some erb exercises and tests but i can't seem to find how to split a stupid line that is too long in my editor. I've already tried using \n and \ but it doesn't work as soon as I run it in terminal.

Here is the code:

```
erb_string = "

 <h1><%= me[:name] + '\\'s ' + 'Blog'%></h1>

 <ul>
    <% animals.each do |animal| %>
    <li><%= animal.upcase.reverse %></li>
<% end %>
 </ul>

 <p><%= 'My name is ' + me[:name] + ', my eyes are ' + me[:eyes] + '.' %></p>

 <p><%= 'Let\\'s do some numbers! '  + numbers.last.to_s + '! is ' + numbers.inject(:*).to_s %></p> # I want to split this line in my editor because it is too long.
"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   <p><%= 'Let\'s do some numbers! '  + \
   numbers.last.to_s + '! is ' + \
   numbers.inject(:*).to_s %></p>
```

this should work.
if it didn't work it was probably because you used two backslashes to escape the single quote and the first backlash escaped the second one so the single quote was not escaped.

Btw, when you have a string containing single quotes, you'd better encapsulate that in double quotes so you don't have to escape the single quotes.

Comment: thank you for your prompt reply! 

I tried your suggestions but it still doesnt works. 

I always try to use single quotes inside double quotes but the problem here is that i cant use them because all those blocks are inside the erb_string :S

Comment: nope :( i get this error as soon as i run it:
 
      $ ruby erb_example.rb
erb_example.rb:21: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting $end
<p><%= "Let's do some numbers! "  + \

Comment: did you also replace the double slashes with a single slash here? `<%= me[:name] + '\\'s ' + 'Blog'%>`

Comment: Well, i tried that before posting here but i end up with the same kind of error:
  
`$ ruby erb_example.rb
erb_example.rb:19: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting $end
<p><%= 'My name is ' + me[:name] + ', m...`

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you get the error when you make the assignment or when you call eval?

Comment: I'm very sorry, i dont quite understand you. Ive been playing with ruby ad rails for only a week. I get these error when i run the file in terminal. But i guess my problem here isnt that imporant right now. I'll continue doing some more exercices and if i get to solve it, ill come back here to post the solution. Thanks for your time and help Ionut :)

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use the \n for a new line your string has to be in double quotes. So instead of 'Hello \nWorld' you need to use "Hello \nWorld"

Comment: But all that stuff is inside a big string called erb_string. Should i still use double quotes for all my sub strings?

Comment: Yes for the ones that you need to use the new line chachter. You would have to escape, \",  the "new" double quotes like "Hello World \n<%=\" My name is \" %>"

Answer (score 0):

```
rb_string = <<EOL

Lot's of cool
ruby an html and javascript stuff
That includes all the happy new lines that you want
so that you can read it.

EOL
```

EOL and arbitrary string.  And the ending EOL must be at the beginning of a line and all by itself.